# Using integration to find the area of horizontal cross section of a cone

Tags: integration, area

> Assume the volume of cone. The base of the cone is a circle with radius $r$, and height of cone is $h$, if we have a thin slice of the cone, that is a horizontal cross section with a distance $x$ away from the base, what is the area of this cross section in terms of $r,h$?

I understand that the question is telling me that the area of the horizontal cross section is divided into many "rectangles". Thus the area will be just length multiply by the change in height.

However I cannot visualise it, the area is $A= \pi r^2 (1 - \frac{x}{h})^2$ why is this so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to find/draw a diagram with the variables you mentioned, so I am going to explain my answer based on the following diagram I picked off from the internet:

[image]

You are being asked to find the area of the light-green circle.

You’ll notice that $\triangle ADE\sim\triangle ABC$ and so $\dfrac rR=\dfrac kH$

 But $k=H-h$ so $\dfrac rR=1-\dfrac hH$, i.e. $$r=R\left(1-\frac hH\right)$$ and the area of the cross-section is $\pi r^2$.

I think the term “thin slice” is misleading and should be replaced with “cross-section”.

Comment: nice picture :-)

Comment: why must we square $(1- x/h)$?

Comment: It is called similarity. Area of a figure scales up/down by $a^2$ as the linear dimensions (in this case, radius of circle) scale up/down by $a$ respectively.